# ngx-google-places-autocomplete input not updating selected string

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using the `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` plugin on a form where we need the user to enter a location for in a search form.

However, if I were to begin typing a place such as 'Por' and then select 'Porto' from the populated autocomplete dropdown and then submit the form, the value of the submitted in my formBuilder array is 'Por' instead of the full selected value?

My component html is (I've removed other fields for brevity);

```
<form class="search" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(searchForm.value)">
    <div  class="form-row" *ngIf="formState == 'active'">
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-group special-input" ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='googlePlacesOptions' formControlName="location" #placesRef="ngx-places" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then in my component.ts I have the following (again reduced for brevity);

```
googlePlacesOptions = {
    types: [],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'PT' }
};

constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private service: SearchService, private http: Http) {
        this.searchForm = fb.group({
            'location': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        });
    }

submit(form: any): void {
        ... here the value is partial and not the fully selected string
}
```

Am I missing something here to enable this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and neither using NgModel or FormControl was getting the autocompleted value from the input. This is probably due to some conflict with the original js lib.

To solve I used @ViewChild to get access to the input and get the value from there.

In your html template add #addressInput on the input:

```
<form class="search" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(searchForm.value)">
<div  class="form-row" *ngIf="formState == 'active'">
    <div class="col">
        <input #addressInput class="form-group special-input" ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='googlePlacesOptions' formControlName="location" #placesRef="ngx-places" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your component.ts:

```
@ViewChild('addressInput')
addressInput: ElementRef;

...

submit(form: any): void {
    // here you can now get the full input string:
   const inputValue = this.addressInput.nativeElement.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem for others .. USE `patchValue` to update form like  this in submit
`this.FormName.patchValue({address:inputValue});`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onAddressChange` event in `ngx-google-places-autocomplete` component.

So below is my html template:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="address" 
          ngx-google-places-autocomplete [options]='googlePlacesOptions' (onAddressChange)="handleAddressChange($event)"/>
```

Handle your form field update in `handleAddressChange` function in you component.ts file. Mine looks like below;

```
 handleAddressChange(address: any) {
    this.form.get('address').setValue(address.formatted_address);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

We opted to update the form with the result from google autocomplete:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const autoComplete = this.mapService.getGoogleAutocomplete(this.autocompleteGoogle.nativeElement);
    this.search$.asObservable()
        .debounceTime(250)
        .map(() => autoComplete)
        .switchMap(() => this.mapService.getGoogleAutocomplete$(autoComplete))
        .subscribe((place: any) => {
            this.Form.get('location').setValue(place.formatted_address);
        });
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on why you used this approach? I assume the mapService is service you write and call to an api, etc?

Comment: The first call 'getGoogleAutocomplete' sets different options to the input, like restrictions to a specific country.

 new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(el, { componentRestrictions: { country: "BE" } });


The second call 'getGoogleAutocomplete$' adds a listener to see if a change is made:

return Observable.create((ob: Observer<google.maps.places.PlaceResult>) => {
   const listenerHandler = autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    ob.next(autocomplete.getPlace());
   });
   return () => listenerHandler.remove();
  });